# gradle task not recognizing the sonar-project.properties file in project workspace

Tags: sonarqube

I have created a sample spring boot project along with sonarqube gradle plugin in it .I have add all the needed properties like login token to sonar-project.properties.But while running gradle task I get exception of authentication

Gradle plugin added

`plugins {  id "org.sonarqube" version "2.6"    }`

[Screenshot of project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pOnH.png)

Answer (score 3):

I also suffered from this pain and my workaround was to parse the settings file and apply it:

```
sonarqube {
  // this is silly but specifying the actual settings file is not supported
  properties {
    def props = new Properties()
    file("sonar-project.properties").withInputStream { props.load(it) }
    props.each {
      property("${it.key}", "${it.value}")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great solution that works for me. It avoids to have double properties in two different files. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Gradle analysis doesn't read `sonar-project.properties`. Instead, add those values to `build.gradle` [as shown in the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforGradle-Passingmanualproperties/overridingdefaults)

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.login", "xxxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to fetch the "xxxxxxx" login part from another file. How should I go about it. I am using sonarqube in android environment.